# Is there a general logit -type function (or another sigmodal function with similar shape) which returns f(x) between 0 and 1?

Tags: analysis, logistic-regression

I'm looking for a general function that can fit experimental data that has a profile/trend similar to the logit function $f(x) = \log x/(1-x)$, but where all f(x) values are between 0 and 1.

Is there a generalised version of the logit function, or any other transformed sigmoidal function, that I can scale and fit my data below?

f(0.005) = 0.005

f(0.04) = 0.06

f(0.1) = 0.22

f(0.2) = 0.37

f(0.3) = 0.47

f(0.4) = 0.48

f(0.5) = 0.53

f(0.6) = 0.55

f(0.7) = 0.56

f(0.8) = 0.58

f(0.9) = 0.66

f(0.96) = 0.79

f(0.999) = 1.00

I'm also attaching an image of the plot.
Thanks!

[curve_fit_problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z435n.jpg)

Comment: what about the probit function?

Answer (score 0):

What about this one?
$$f(x)=4(x-0.5)^3+0.5$$

There is no logarithm or exponential, but the shape of the curve is very similar.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite a good fit to
$$ x + .684 x (1-x)+8.98 x^2 (1-x)-48.6 x^3 (1-x)+79.3 x^4 (1-x)-45.7 x^5 (1-x) $$
obtained by linear least squares.

[image]